# Within same line, have a center element and right-most element

Tags: css

I had posted the question once to http://doctype.com/within-same-line-have-center-element-right-most-element, but didn't get a good answer for that. I posted it here and hopefully will get a good feedback ;)

```
<div style="float:right">
    right most, same line as hello world and will not push hello world!
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">hello world</div>
```

Currently, the right most element, will push the "hello world" out from center of the page. How can I avoid this?

I wish

- Hello world is still at center
- The right element is still same line as Hello world
- The right element is at right most
- Both are top most

Thanks.

I tried some suggestion by others but it won't work.

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;"> 
  Hello World 
  <div style="float:right">right most, same line as hello world and will not push hello world!</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

For the above code, I tested with IE 8. They will not be at same line. And I tested with firefox 3.6.8, The "Hello World" will be pushed toward left by the right side element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:relative` on the containing div and `position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;` on the rightmost div:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%; position:relative;"> 
  Hello World 
  <div style="right:0px; top:0px; position:absolute;">right most, same line as hello world and will not push hello world!</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

When `position:relative` is used, any absolutely positioned elements inside are offset to that relatively positioned ancestor.  See [this blog post](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for further examples.

Demo - http://jsbin.com/itene

Comment: Another example of not comprehending the CSS model and thus the plague of resorting to `position`.

Comment: @John I must have missed your answer, else i would have gladly upvoted it in recognition of its superiority.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
  <div style="float:left; margin-left:400px;">Hello World </div>
  <div style="float:right">right most, same line as hello world and will not push hello world!</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[See the DEMO here.](http://jsbin.com/evelo/2)

You might want to adjust the value for `margin-left` in the `hello world` div.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a line height for the centered div and use position: relative for the second:

```
<div style="text-align:center; line-height: 50px;">hello world</div>
<div style="line-height: 50px; position: relative; top: -50px; float:right; z-index: 1">
    right most, same line as hello world and will not push hello world!
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I realize both stuffs are shifting down. Is it possible to maintain them as top most too?

Comment: Yes, by altering the line-height. Try a value less than 50px.